# 12.04 AMI in ap-northeast-2 (seoul)

Tags: 12.04

I need a 12.04 (Precise) EC2 AMI (instance store type) in the ap-northeast-2 (seoul) region, but cannot find it in http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/ .

Any idea if it will be available in the future, and when?

Comment: This sounds like a good question for the Amazon AWS Developer forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com

Comment: But these Ubuntu AMIs are maintained by Canonical, not Amazon, right?